# Any FileUpload replacement to work side by side with ICEfaces and Spring Web Flow?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, icefaces, spring-webflow

FileUpload control from ICEfaces conflicts with Spring Web Flow 2.0. If anyone knows another FileUpload JSF control that work OK with Spring Web Flow and doesn't conflict with ICEfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Did u have achieved fileUpload in icefaces + Spring Web Flow 2.0?